# How to create Mesh and solid from python, to be imported to CAD software

Tags: python, cnc, 3d-mapping

EDITED: Due to progress made, the problem is now different.

I want to be able to generate a mesh from point cloud (3D scanned), and then turn that into a solid, so that i can import it into CAD program such as fusion.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking for. Do you have some sample code where you have tried to do this? If so, please post the sample code.

Comment: ok so some context: I have made some progress in this matter so it'll be easier to explain. I have generated the point cloud, then turned that into a mesh in meshlab, then turned that into a solid in fusion 360, and in the CAM workspace set the stock to the solid that i created. now the surface of the object that is to be milled has the profile of the object that was scanned. what i hope to be able to do now is create a mesh and turn it into a solid in python, so that i can skip two steps.

Comment: Is there a specific algorithm you are trying to implement in Python? Somethlng along the lines of "I have a point cloud where each point is x, y, z and I want to turn that into a mesh using algorithm X". Sorry, I'm not familiar with CNC so I don't know what you mean by "turn it into a solid".